# How can I add custom CSS to the result of the markdown command?

Tags: linux, html, markdown

New to markdown...

I have a very simple markdown file, I am using the markdown command

```
markdown something.md -o something.html
```

Is it possible for me to inject my own css into the `something.html` file

---

I tried to insert the css as raw html in the markdown and then use raw-html flag when processing the markdown, I am probably doing something wrong because `markdown` is treating the html as text..

here is the start of `something.md`

```
<html>
 <head>
  <style>
    <link res="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
  </style>
</head>
# Testing md
## testing md2
</html>
```

and here is the result of executing `markdown -o something.html -f +html something.md`  is:

```
<p><html>
<head></p>
<p></head></p>
<h1>Testing md</h1>
<h2>testing md2</h2>
</html></p>
```

Comment: You can use raw html in the input and compile with `-f html`, edit the output, or use [pandoc](https://pandoc.org).

Comment: @Devon I updated my question...